# Default Ruby version set with RVM not recognized by system

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, rvm

I'm trying to get the system to use the Ruby version I've set with RVM. The following commands produce this output:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p180
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Here's the contents of my PATH:
    `PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Also:

```
$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
$ whereis rvm
rvm: /usr/bin/rvm /usr/share/man/man1/rvm.1.gz
```

I assume this is an issue of environmental variables, but I don't really know what to do beyond that.

I've tried `rvm system`, then `rvm list` and `rvm current` only list 1.9.2 with `ruby --version` listing 1.8.7 still

I've also tried adding `export /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:$PATH` to .bashrc, then restarting and still.

Answer (score 2):

The ruby-1.9.2../bin path needs to be in your PATH in front of any other ruby. rvm use 1.9.2 should be putting it there, not sure why it would not. Mine is a little different since I use a private rvm installation (in my ~/)

Maybe this will help you:

```
jeremy@octavian:~$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
jeremy@octavian:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
jeremy@octavian:~$ which ruby
/home/jeremy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
jeremy@octavian:~$ echo $PATH
/home/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/jeremy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/jeremy/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: isn't rvm only intended to be installed to `~/`? I thought installing rvm to the system would introduce problems...?

Comment: @Thufir The OP's RVM was installed here: `usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180`. I agree it should be in home, maybe that wasn't being universally recommended in 2012.